Print loss at each epoch or each index_data in Pytorch
I'm newer in Pytorch, so please help, I'm confused about the position to calculate epoch_loss in training dataset:
def train(net,trainloader,epochs,use_gpu = True): 
    ..
    net.train()
    # Train the network
    for epoch in range(epochs): 
        print ("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch+1, epochs))
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            images, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
            
            running_loss += loss.item()
                        
            epoch_loss = running_loss/len(trainloader.dataset)
    
            print('Loss: {}'.format(epoch_loss))  

Where I must print Loss, like the code or at each epoch like below
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    ...
    epoch_loss = running_loss/len(trainloader.dataset)
    print('Loss: {}'.format(epoch_loss)) 
    


It depends on what want to print.
Batch loss is the loss of your model on a particular batch.
Epoch loss is the average of all batch losses for an epoch.
If you want to print the batch loss, you print running_loss after every batch:
def train(net,trainloader,epochs,use_gpu = True): 
    net.train()
    # Train the network
    for epoch in range(epochs): 
        print ("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch+1, epochs))
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            images, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(images)
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item()
                        
            epoch_loss = running_loss/len(trainloader.dataset)
    
            print('Batch loss: {}'.format(loss.item()))

If, on the other hand, you want to print the epoch loss, you should use your second option
